# Deleting memory in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I'm trying to rewrite my code using dynamic memory allocation, and I'm using, amongst others, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) (and answers) to help me. So following Johanes Shaub's advice, I've declared my 2d array as:

```
double (*q_1_matrix)[TIME] = new double[SPACE][TIME];
```

When I run my code now everything seems to work fine. But when I add the following line to deallocate the memory again:

```
for(i = 0; i < SPACE; ++i) {
    delete [] q_1_matrix[i];
}
delete [] q_1_matrix;
```

then I get the warning: 
deleting array ‘*(q_1_matrix + ((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 800ul)))’ [enabled by default] delete [] q_1_matrix[i];
and subsequently I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>> myvec(A, std::vector<double>(B))` and these kinds of errors will just disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `new` call is actually creating 1 big chunk of memory. It is only indexed as a 2-dimensional array.
you can just call `delete[] q_1_matrix;` (without the for loop).

Answer (score 3):

The question you refer to restricts answers to using `new`, but you almost certainly don't need `new`.

It is *far* simpler to use the standard library; then, all your worries go away:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> myvec(SPACE, std::vector<double>(TIME));
```

And if you instead wrap a `std::vector<double>(SPACE*TIME)` in a class that simulates 2D indexing, so much the better.

Anyway, if you really must manage memory yourself, recall that you're creating *one* big chunk of dynamic memory here (with the type and dimensions of a `double[SPACE][TIME]`), so you must free it only once:

```
delete[] q_1_matrix;
```